# How can I populate a tableView with an NSSet? (swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I have a Person Class in tableView1, then in TableView2, the user adds brands to associate with the person.  My fetch request is trying to get back the person they selected and populate the tableView's rows with the associated brands of that person, but I'm stuck here:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let brandSetAllObjects = brandSet?.allObjects


        let brand = brandSetAllObjects as? Brand[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = brand.valueForKey("name") as? String


        return cell
    }
```

Fetch:

```
 //Helper Function to Fetch Core Data
    func fetchCoreData() {
        //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")


        //3
        var error: NSError?

        let fetchedResults =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
            error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

        if let results = fetchedResults as? [Person] {
            for selectedPerson in results {
                brandSet = selectedPerson.brands
                println(brandSet)
            }

        } else {
            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
```

classes:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Brand: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var people: NSSet


}

import Foundation
import CoreData

class Person: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var brands: NSSet

    func addBrandsObject(value: Brand) {
        self.mutableSetValueForKey("brands").addObject(value)
    }

}
```

Comment: This line of code confuses me a little, could you elaborate a bit on this - `let brand = brandSetAllObjects as? Brand[indexPath.row]`?

Comment: Someone in an older answer had suggested getting the NSSet into an array via .allObjects...so I was trying to cast (unsuccessfuly) that array into something I could work with to populate my tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular order that is sortable that you want the table view's contents to be displayed in?

Instead of directly accessing the data structure "`Brand`", you could have a data manager that manipulates the data in a uniform fashion. You could keep all of the `Brand` information in an `NSSet` and then have a method on your data manager that returns an `NSArray` (possibly called `brandArray`). The data manager could take the contents of the `NSSet`, add them to an array, and then sort the array so that they're in a uniform order and return that array.

On the `UITableView` side, just replace `Brand[indexPath.row]` with something like `dataManager.brandArray[indexPath.row]`.

My suggestion for a data manager would be to make a class that will be implemented as a [singleton](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/). Step 4 of [this tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/birds-cats-dogs/) does a pretty good job of explaining how to setup a data manager.

Side note: a data manager is just a concept, not a strict class or type of object. It can be any object that manages data, though this is generally executed as a singleton that can be accessed from any other class in your project.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to set up the data manager?  I can't find any documentation or tutorials on it...

Comment: I updated my answer with links to how to make a singleton and how to make a data manager. I hope that helps!